# Cannot Get Response From The Server If The Request Is GET In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tomcat

I have a simple react component with just one anchor tag `<a href="/Connection/react">Tomcat</a>` which sends a `GET` request to the tomcat server, Both react and tomcat are running on localhost at port 3000 and 8080 respectively, I've also set a proxy to `http://localhost:8080` in the `package.json` but for some reason if the request method is `GET` I don't get any response back from the server. So far the only thing that has worked for me is getting response back through `POST` requests using `forms`.

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080",
```

Comment: what's your base uri backend set to?

Comment: @MartinaCarter I'm not aware of how to set or get the value for the base uri, Can you please tell me how to do that? Or should I share the code snippet of the web.xml?